# Is it possible to hibernate BOTH windows and ubuntu in a dual boot setup?

Tags: dual-boot, hibernate

I've searched through the related questions posted here and didn't find this particular situation.

I have Windows 10 that I often hibernate in order to boot again onto ubuntu 18.10 (which i'm still new to) for work and programming stuff.

However, I noticed that all my attempts of hibernating ubuntu while windows being **currently** hibernated failed (I tried `sudo pm-hibernate` and the other variants with avail). This is why I suspected that probably a double hibernation is not possible.

My boot is configured to show the grub menu first.

So, can I hibernate both ubuntu and windows in the same machine?

Comment: I won't recommend you to Hibernate Ubuntu and then Boot into Windows OS. It can lead to a terrible loss of data. Kindly refer this weblink for more information: https://superuser.com/questions/39532/hibernating-and-booting-into-another-os-will-my-filesystems-be-corrupted

Comment: @ManuMathur .. I see. Thank you for the resource